# Probability in R data frames

Tags: r, probability

I am working on bigger probability problem using naive bayes, but for right now I am stuck on how to get a smaller part of the problem. Here is an example of the df I am working on.

```
d = data.frame(work=c("unemployed","govt worker", "teacher", "unemployed"),
               race=c("white","black", "white", "white"),
               sex=c("male","female", "female", "male"))
> d
         work  race    sex
1  unemployed white   male
2 govt worker black female
3     teacher white female
4  unemployed white   male
```

The question Im trying to answer is:
What is the probability a white male is unemployed?

I think the first step is building a likelihood table but I don't know how to go about creating one.

Any idea on how to go about this?
Thank you.

Comment: `table(d)/sum(table(d))`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
# set (equal) probability for each row
d$prob <- 1/nrow(d)

# group by race and sex, sum probabilities
d <- aggregate(prob ~ race + sex, d, sum)
```